# Проблема с кроссбраузерностью в Internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, scss

недавно начал изучать верстку и столкнулся с проблемой кроссбраузерности при верстке макета на флексах. На первом скриншоте показан список преимуществ который показывается в Internet Explorer, а на другом показывается как выглядит в других браузера, включая Edge. Еще у сайта в Internet Explorer после самого содержимого идет прокрутка далее, с белым фоном, хотя такого нет в других браузерах. Далее приложу код на HTML и Scss и чистом CSS если кому нужно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.features {
  height: 690px;
}

.features_main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 121px 47px 124px 47px;
}

.features_column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.features_column:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 94px;
}

.features_item {
  text-align: center;
}

.features_item:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 94px;
}

.features_title {
  font-family: "Raleway" sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #2d3033;
  margin: 34px 0 25px 0;
}

.features_text {
  font-family: "Raleway" sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #6c7279;
}
```

```css
.features {
    height: 690px;
    &_main {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        margin: 121px 47px 124px 47px;
    }
    &_column {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        &:nth-child(2) {
            margin: 0 94px;
        }
    }
    &_item {
        text-align: center;
        &:first-child {
            margin-bottom: 94px;
        }
    } 
    &_title {
        font-family: "Raleway" sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: normal;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        color: #2d3033;
        margin: 34px 0 25px 0;
    }
    &_text {
        font-family: "Raleway" sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 1.5;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        color: #6c7279;
    }
```

```html
<div class="features">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="features_main">
                <div class="features_column">
                    <div class="features_item">
                        <div class="features_img">
                            <img src="images/features1.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="features_title">
                            Easily Customised
                        </div>
                        <div class="features_text">
                            Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="features_item">
                        <div class="features_img">
                            <img src="images/features4.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="features_title">
                            Clean Code
                        </div>
                        <div class="features_text">
                            Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="features_column">
                    <div class="features_item">
                        <div class="features_img">
                            <img src="images/features2.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="features_title">
                            Responsive REady
                        </div>
                        <div class="features_text">
                            Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="features_item">
                        <div class="features_img">
                            <img src="images/features5.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="features_title">
                            Ready to Ship
                        </div>
                        <div class="features_text">
                            Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="features_column">
                    <div class="features_item">
                        <div class="features_img">
                            <img src="images/features3.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="features_title">
                            Modern Design
                        </div>
                        <div class="features_text">
                            Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="features_item">
                        <div class="features_img">
                            <img src="images/features6.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="features_title">
                            Download for Free
                        </div>
                        <div class="features_text">
                            Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Зачем вам Internet Explorer? От него даже майкрософт давно избавился

Comment: А разве, когда проверяют на кроссбраузерность не проверяют и его тоже?

Comment: Это было лет десять назад, сейчас никто в здравом уме уже не проверяет (ну или проверяет, но за большие деньги, компенсирующие получаемые страдания)

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь в последующей вёрстке сайтом caniuse.com
В нём описано, что IE поддерживает flex начиная с 10 версии с префиксом -ms-, а также имеет некоторые известные баги.
[image: сайт caniuse.com]